# "UI components" with "GUI components" with "UI/UX components"

Tags: controls, ui-element

Depending on the framework, the name of these ones (buttons, input fields and also non-interactive ones like admonition blocks) is different. I am thinking which term I need to use being the developer of the UI kit ("UI/UX kit"? "GUI kit"?) like Bootstrap or Element UI.

From my view point of the logic, the "GUI components" and "GUI kit" are most correct terms, but I cold be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The term GUI (Graphical User Interface) is an obsolete name from the times of the Command Line

UX/UI Kit is just too ambiguous as it mixes two different fields of design. Also kit (or toolkit) implies a complete package (with docs and code)

**I suggest referring to it as a 'UI Components Library' instead**:

- Its subject is clear (i.e. UI components)
- Library implies it has reusable elements one can tap into

Answer (score 0):

UI does not include only graphical elements but also non-graphical elements like CLI or voice-based interfaces, interactions etc.. while GUI to a type of UI that allows users to interact through graphical elements such as icons, buttons, and windows.